# LockerService seems to be blocking adding new properties to JS objects in LWC

Tags: locker-service, lightning-web-components

I am facing issue with LWC, probably connected to the LockerService's Proxy objects.

**My code**

I am getting the list of custom objects defined in one of my Apex classes by calling Apex method from LWC JS file:

```
getSettingsForConfigType({configType: this.codeConfigType})
            .then(settings => {
                //this.fieldList = settings;
                this.prepopulateConfig(settings);
            })
            .catch(error => {
                this.toastError(error.body.message);
            })
```

**The problem**

The problem is I need to populate the `settings` object returned from Apex with additional field. This field is not defined in Apex (and I don't want it to be defined, it will be used only on LWC side). Whenever I try to add new field called `fieldValue` either with `obj.fieldValue = ...` or `obj['fieldValue'] = ...` syntax I get forrowing error:

`TypeError: 'set' on proxy: trap returned falsish for property 'fieldValue'`

**Question**

Is there any way to overcome this limitation or maybe I am missing something here?

**P.S. Dirty workaround**

`settings = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(settings));`

However, it seems to be a bit ugly trick. That's why I posted the question :-)

Comment: P.S. This has nothing to do with locker service, it has to do with not mutating the cache of a cachable Apex method. If you were allowed to modify the object, you'd mess up the cache, so the object is read-only to prevent this from happening.

Comment: Thanks. I don't know why, but I couldn't find the question linked above. It's surely a duplicate.

Answer (score 0):

Try using ES6 syntax, looks much cleaner and simpler.

```
const fieldValue = (whatever data to add)
settings = {...settings, fieldValue};
```